# How to wait for methods to finish then do new action?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

I'm setting up my architechture to use Cef.Offscreen. In order to make it easy to work with I have divided some parts. But I run into a problem that controller loading finshes and serves a view before everything has been able to load.

Here's my structure --> **Controller**

```
public ActionResult InitBrowser()
    {

        ICefSharpRenderer renderer = RendererSingelton.GetInstance();
        //Try to render something in default appdomain
        renderer.LoginToTradingView(null, null);

        ViewBag.SiteTitle = BrowserActions.RunScriptInNamedBrowser("loginbrowser", @"(function() {return document.title;} )();");

        ViewBag.ImagesixtyfourUrl = BrowserActions.TakeScreenshot("loginbrowser");

        //this is returned to fast, we have to wait for all

        return View(); 
    }
```

I have this class to get do some basic actions and initialize if needed.

```
public class CefSharpRenderer : MarshalByRefObject, ICefSharpRenderer
{
    private ChromiumWebBrowser _browser;
    private TaskCompletionSource<JavascriptResponse> _taskCompletionSource;
    private string _name;

    public void LoginToTradingView(string url, string browserName)
    {
        CheckIfCefIsInitialized();
        BrowserFactory.GetBrowserInstance(@"https://se.tradingview.com/", "loginbrowser");

    }


   public void CreateBrowserAndGoToUrl(string url, string browserName)
   {
        CheckIfCefIsInitialized();
        BrowserFactory.GetBrowserInstance(url, "browserName");

    }

    public void CheckIfCefIsInitialized()
    {
        if (!Cef.IsInitialized)
        {
            var settings = new CefSettings();
            var assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(GetType().Assembly.CodeBase).LocalPath);

            settings.BrowserSubprocessPath = Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe");
            settings.ResourcesDirPath = assemblyPath;
            settings.LocalesDirPath = Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "locales");

            var osVersion = Environment.OSVersion;
            //Disable GPU for Windows 7
            if (osVersion.Version.Major == 6 && osVersion.Version.Minor == 1)
            {
                // Disable GPU in WPF and Offscreen examples until #1634 has been resolved
                settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");
            }

            //Perform dependency check to make sure all relevant resources are in our output directory.
            Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: false, cefApp: null);
        }
    }

}
```

I get my browserinstance here and connected the events to be fired.

```
public static class BrowserFactory
{

    public static ChromiumWebBrowser GetBrowserInstance(string _url, string browsername)
    {
        if (!BrowserContainer.CheckIfBrowserExists(browsername))
        {
            ChromiumWebBrowser _browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(_url);
            _browser.LoadingStateChanged += BrowserEvents.OnLoadingStateChanged;
            BrowserContainer.AddDataHolder(browsername, new DataBrowserHolder { BrowserName = browsername, ChromiumWebBrow = _browser });

            return _browser;
        }

        return null;

    }
}
```

Browserevent loads correct page.

```
    public static class BrowserEvents
{
    public static void OnLoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsLoading == false)
        {
            ChromiumWebBrowser cwb = (ChromiumWebBrowser)sender;

            if (cwb.Address == "https://se.tradingview.com/")
            {
                BrowserActions.LogInToTradingView("xxxxx", "yyyyyyy", "loginbrowser");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Last my browseractions, spare med for the thread sleeps it's just under construction and it works atm.

```
  public static class BrowserActions
{
    public static void LogInToTradingView(string twusername, string twpassword, string browserName)
    {
        ChromiumWebBrowser _dataholder = BrowserContainer.GetDataHolderByName(browserName).ChromiumWebBrow;

        IFrame ifww = _dataholder.GetMainFrame();
        //    var lull = @"(function() { var serielength = TradingView.bottomWidgetBar._widgets.backtesting._reportWidgetsSet.reportWidget._data.filledOrders.length; return serielength; })();";
        //    JavascriptResponse _js = Task.Run(async () => { return await _browser.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync(lull); }).Result;

        ifww.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(@"(function() { window.document.getElementsByClassName('tv-header__link tv-header__link--signin js-header__signin')[0].click();})();");

        //  var loginusernamescript =  
        var loginpasswordscript = @"(function() { window.document.getElementsByClassName('tv-control-material-input tv-signin-dialog__input tv-control-material-input__control')[1].value= " + twpassword + "; })();";
        var clkloginbtn = @"(function() { document.getElementsByClassName('tv-button tv-button--no-border-radius tv-button--size_large tv-button--primary_ghost tv-button--loader')[0].click();})();";
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        ifww.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(@"(function() { window.document.getElementsByClassName('tv-control-material-input tv-signin-dialog__input tv-control-material-input__control')[0].click();})();");
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        ifww.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(@"(function() { window.document.getElementsByClassName('tv-control-material-input tv-signin-dialog__input tv-control-material-input__control')[0].value = '" + twusername + "';})();");
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        ifww.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(@"(function() { window.document.getElementsByClassName('tv-control-material-input tv-signin-dialog__input tv-control-material-input__control')[1].click();})();");
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        ifww.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(@"(function() { window.document.getElementsByClassName('tv-control-material-input tv-signin-dialog__input tv-control-material-input__control')[1].value = '" + twpassword + "';})();");
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        ifww.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(@"(function() { document.getElementsByClassName('tv-button tv-button--no-border-radius tv-button--size_large tv-button--primary_ghost tv-button--loader')[0].click();})();");

    }

    public static string TakeScreenshot(string browserName)
    {
        try
        {
            Bitmap img = Task.Run(async () => { return await BrowserContainer.GetDataHolderByName(browserName).ChromiumWebBrow.ScreenshotAsync(); }).Result;
            //    object mgss = img.Clone();
            string baseen = ExtraFunctions.ToBase64String(img, ImageFormat.Png);
            return baseen;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var x = e.InnerException;
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static string RunScriptInNamedBrowser(string browserName, string script)
    {
        try
        {
            string str = Task.Run(async () => { return await BrowserContainer.GetDataHolderByName(browserName).ChromiumWebBrow.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync(script); }).Result.ToString();
            //    object mgss = img.Clone();
            return str;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var x = e.InnerException;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I get my browser actions to report back to my controller so that I can wait for them to finish?**

Comment: Can the method not return type `Task` and be awaited? If a return value is needed, why not use a `ref` and check whether it has a value?

Comment: A method named `ExecuteJavaScriptAsync` almost certainly returns a `Task`. Since you aren't awaiting it or returning it, your code is effectively broken. I suggest that you look at your compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

For a `Task` asynchronous operation to report back, it's possible to use `Progress<T>`. How that's done is detailed in [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/). The key is:

```
var progressIndicator = new Progress<int>(ReportProgress);
```

This creates a `Progress<T>` object that can indicate how far a task is complete, and also call a custom method `(ReportProgress)` at set intervals. You can create a custom class if necessary instead of using `int`.

So your browser actions can report back to the controller with the progress reporting method until everything is complete.